# Laravel 5.4 ChartJs - Use Collections/Arrays as Labels and Data

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I wanted the chart's labels and data to be dynamic.

To get things started, I have a function called `search` in my `Controller` and it has a query like this:

```
$total_cost = DB::raw('SUM(qty * cost) as total_cost');
$total_grossrev = DB::raw('(SUM(price * qty)) as total_grossrev');
$total_profit = DB::raw('(SUM(price * qty)) - (SUM(qty * cost)) as total_profit');

$period = DB::raw('date(created_at) as period');
$format = 'j F Y h:i A';

$salesanalysis = DB::table('orders')
    ->whereDate('created_at','>=', $request->datefrom)
    ->whereDate('created_at', '<=', $request->dateto)
    ->where('status', 'served')
    ->select($total_cost, $total_grossrev, $total_profit, $period, 'created_at')
    ->groupBy('period')
    ->get();
```

And in my script to have the chart, this is my structure:

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/Chart.min.js') }}"></script>

<script>
    let salesAnalysisChart = document.getElementById('salesAnalysisChart').getContext('2d');

    let barChart = new Chart(salesAnalysisChart, {
        responsive: true,
        type:'bar',
        data:{
            labels:[ //period of salesanalysis ],
            datasets:[{
                label:'Sales',
                data:[
                    // total_profit of salesanalysis
                ],
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(73, 187, 235, 0.7)',
                hoverBorderWidth: 1,
                hoverBorderColor: '#000'
            }]
        },
        options:{
            maintainAspectRatio: false,
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: true,
                    }
                }]
            },

            legend:{
                position:'bottom',
                display:false,
            },

            layout:{
                padding: 0,
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

Also, the `period` of salesanalysis is gonna be parsed by `Carbon` with the use of `$format`. So I thought of using this syntax:

```
{{\Carbon\Carbon::parse($collection->period)->format($format)}}
```

The bottomline is, how am I gonna use the `collection` for the `label` and `data` of ChartJs.

Comment: You just need to return it as a one dimensional array

Comment: adding `->toArray()` will convert the collection into array right? After that how will I apply it in the script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow I managed to solve the problem.

In my `controller`, I did a query and converted it into array:

```
$salesanalysisarray = DB::table('orders')
                    ->whereDate('created_at','>=', $request->datefrom)
                    ->whereDate('created_at', '<=', $request->dateto)
                    ->where('status', 'served')
                    ->select($total_cost, $total_grossrev, $total_profit, $period, 'created_at')
                    ->groupBy('period')
                    ->get()
                    ->toArray();
```

And in my `script`, I initialized another `array` and did a loop to push each data into the `array` itself:

```
    var periodArray = new Array();
    var profitArray = new Array();
    var costArray = new Array();

    @forelse($salesanalysis as $analysis) 
    periodArray.push("{{\Carbon\Carbon::parse($analysis->created_at)->format($format)}}");
    profitArray.push("{{$analysis->total_profit}}");
    costArray.push("{{$analysis->total_cost}}");
    @empty
    @endforelse
```

Answer (score 0):

At the bottom of the view create a buildChart function that takes the labels, data, and any other as paremeters. Pass them over using the PHP implode method and return the imploded variable in blade to a function that creates chart.

```
//View
buildChart({{ $variable }}, ect)
```

Comment: `$variable` is considered as the collection?